The training loss fluctuates a lot, while the validation loss is ok, what could be the problem?
I am training a neural network (CNN) for a regression task (object area estimation in images). My training loss always fluctuates quiete a lot, while my validation loss is ok compare to the training loss.

I don't see anything problematic, differences between the two are expected, maybe try decreasing the learning step.

Thanks! the learning rate is already quite low: 1e-5. It looks like the training loss is not improving much after the initial drop. But the validation loss keep droping slowly.
